# Determining '< x' values as numeric

Tags: measurements, air-pollution, statistics

I do have a large dataset containing nearly a decade of particulate matter measurements. At the lower precision limit of the measuring instrument, there are values given like `< 8`. For statistical analysis however, a defined value is needed.

What is the best possible way to deal with this?

- Replacing it as missing values?
- Replacing it by `8` or even `7` (`< 8`)?
- Assuming `0`?
- Assuming the mean value between something like `0` and `8`; e. g. `4`?

*Or is there a better solution, maybe considering the natural background value?*

EDIT:
I'd like to calculate the intra-day- and intra-year distribution, as well as searching for patterns by considering wind directiond and speed.

Comment: **It depends on what you want to measure/calculate.** So we need more info.

Comment: @JanDoggen: Added some more information, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps one standard deviation around the limit of determination would suffice, but it depends upon the range of the dataset you are using, and the accuracy / precision of whatever you are trying to analyse. If the limit of determination, say 7 or 8, has a high frequency relative to other values, then you may have a statistical problem from too uniform a lower limit, in which case, counter-inuitively,  it may be beneficial to introduce synthetic randomness into your lowest value. I sometimes do this when I have to synthesize missing rainfall data.

Comment: In addition to Gordon Stanger's comment: replacing `<8` values by missing values might alter the distribution but replacing `< 8` values by noise (or replacing it by other non-missing values) might yield artificial correlations. Therefore, it might be reasonable to do the noise and the missing-value approach and get a feeling on which one is actually working 'better'. If there are less than approximately 5% (not a fix threshold) I would suggest to use missing values.

Comment: Maybe consider changing the title of your question. Reading the title, I assumed that the question would be focused on programming-related.

Comment: If your data is dense enough, replacing by missing-value may not be a bad idea. But if the data is not sufficiently dense, I would suggest interpolating to the nearest values. Either way the outliers are bad and should be thrown away imo.